# How can i instantiate a static member method template of a class?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to instantiate `My::name()` method for different types passed to it:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace prw
{
    class My
    {
    public:
        template <typename TYPE>
        static std::string name(TYPE v);
    };
}

std::string prw::My::name(int v)
{
    return "Ok";
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << prw::My::name(1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler output:**

```
main.cpp:14:17: error: no declaration matches 'std::string prw::My::name(int)'
   14 |     std::string prw::My::name(int v)
      |                 ^~~
main.cpp:10:28: note: candidate is: 'template<class TYPE> static std::string prw::My::name(TYPE)'
   10 |         static std::string name(TYPE v);
      |                            ^~~~
main.cpp:6:11: note: 'class prw::My' defined here
    6 |     class My
      |           ^~
```

By the way stackoverflow tells me that:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Although my question is simple and self-explanatory by just viewing the code and the complirer's output.

What i'm doing wrong? Damn :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to *specialize* the template, not *instantiate* it. The syntax for specialization would be:

```
template<>
std::string prw::My::name(int v)
{
    return "foo";
}
// And if you want to further specialize for other types:
template<>
std::string prw::My::name(bool v)
{
    return "bar";
}
```

*Specialization* defines how the template would work on some type. *Instantiation* causes the compiler to generate the code for it and check its validity earlier than it would normally would. Normally the compiler would do that at the first call site of the function with the specific type but for a couple of reasons you might want to change when that happens (e.g. this lets you define templates outside of your header files). The syntax for explicit instantiation, specifically by means of providing *explicit instantiation definitions* is:

```
namespace prw
{
    class My
    {
    public:
        template <typename TYPE>
        static std::string name(TYPE v)
        {
            return "Ok"; // notice how name has a body now
        }
    };
}

template std::string prw::My::name(int v); // name is instantiated here instead of below


int main()
{
    std::cout << prw::My::name(1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: YOUR ARE A TREASURE ! Thanks a lot! It seems i've not mastered C++ templates yet, although i've spent much time on it! :( TANK YOU A LOT! I've thought that `template<>` goes only if the class itself is templatized.  :( .That's why i've missed it!

Comment: tiny nitpick on wording: Saying that  Instantiation makes the compiler check earliear than it would normally isnt quite right, because if you don't explicitly instantiate it, it will be instantiated at the first call site